# Performance effect of @Transactional at Class level

Tags: java, transactions

Assuming that you put

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class Clazz{ /*many methods here*/}
```

on a class that contains many methods, some of which don't even interact with the database, will there be a performance hit for this sort of catch-all default transaction management on all methods of the class?  Or will the compiler be smart enough to know that if no DB calls are made within some methods of the class, no transaction management needs to be applied?

Also, if the underlying database has good default transaction management, is the annotation on read only methods even necessary?  Would it be better to just leave this off of the class altogether and only use transaction management on methods where multiple writes occur in synchrony and atomicity is absolutely necessary?

Thanks in advance.